# ruby meta: Class.superclass.class == Class

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

```
irb(main):101:0> Class.superclass
=> Module
irb(main):102:0> Class.superclass.class
=> Class
irb(main):103:0> Class.superclass.class == Class
=> true
```

By inheritance, Class < Module < Object < BasicObject
By metaclass(or any other term?), **Class**, **Module**, **Object** and **BasicObject** are all instances of **Class**.

```
irb(main):109:0> Module.class
=> Class
irb(main):172:0> Object.class
=> Class
irb(main):173:0> BasicObject.class
=> Class
irb(main):174:0> Class.class
=> Class
```

How to understand this relationship between Class and Class, Module, Object, BasicObject?
I read some metaprogramming discussion for ruby, but any resource talking about this specific question please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think these could confuse you at first, but after you get it, then you will see the different clearly. I would suggest see these resources:

- [The Ruby Object Model](http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4) by Dave Thomas
- [The Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming) by by Dave Thomas
- [The Ruby Object Model - Structure and Semantics](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html)

Comment: +1, the last link is the one I always recommend for understanding Ruby's object model.

Comment: ++ for the dave thomas link, that video totally cleared it all up for me. Just watched it twice

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video talk on [Ruby internals](http://mwrc2008.confreaks.com/11farley.html). It is well worth a watch and might clear some things up.

Answer (score 1):

This is really interesting question. Here is a link to book, that helped me to understand this clearly: 
[Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)